# How to only let certain users use a command discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Im working on a bot in discord.py rewrite and wondering how to only let me use the .dm command to prevent other people posing as the bot my current code is:

```
@client.command()
async def dm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
    if message.author.id == "751537000036696128":
      for user in users:
        await user.send(message)
        await ctx.send("Success!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method One:**

For the owner only use `@commands.is_owner()` [Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20is_owner#discord.ext.commands.is_owner)

```py
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def dm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
```

**Method Two:**

Do a check for certain attributes [Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20check#discord.ext.commands.check)

```py
def admin_or_testserver(ctx):
    return ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.guild.id == 123456 or ctx.channel != discord.DMChannel

@bot.command()
@commands.check(admin_or_testserver)
async def dm(ctx, users: Greedy[User], *, message):
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@commands.is_owner()` decorator