# how only certain people use the command Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so i make a simple say command u can look my code here :

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(id_channel)

    await channel.send(f"{message}")
    await ctx.send('DONE')
```

as u can see here, I use command has permission that means just administrator can use this command, but I want to know how if just certain people can use this command

user 1 (id)
user 2 (id)
user 3 (id)

oh, yea, I want three users to use this command, how can I do that?

Thank u (:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only let certain users use a command discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222398/how-to-only-let-certain-users-use-a-command-discord-py-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

check the user id of the person who called the command

something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, message):
    if ctx.author.id in list_of_ids:
        channel = bot.get_channel(id_channel)

        await channel.send(f"{message}")
        await ctx.send('DONE')
```