# Allow only two user to use a command discord bot py

Tags: discord.py

Hi I want to use the command for only 2 users with their user id can you help me pls there is my code :

```
python
@bot.command()
async def sub(ctx, vintedurl):
    x = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Discord-test")
    with open("config.json", 'w+') as configedit:
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)] = {}
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["url"] = str(vintedurl)
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["salon"] = str(ctx.channel.name)

        json.dump(configs,configedit,indent=4)
    await ctx.send("Webhook ajouté avec le lien !")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to only let certain users use a command discord.py rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222398/how-to-only-let-certain-users-use-a-command-discord-py-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can either check in your command directly, like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sub(ctx, vintedurl):
    if ctx.author.id not in (123, 456): # your desired IDs here
        return

    x = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Discord-test")
    with open("config.json", 'w+') as configedit:
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)] = {}
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["url"] = str(vintedurl)
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["salon"] = str(ctx.channel.name)

        json.dump(configs,configedit,indent=4)
    await ctx.send("Webhook ajouté avec le lien !")
```

Or you could also create your custom check:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

def custom_check(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id in (123, 456) # your desired IDs here

@bot.command()
@commands.check(custom_check)
async def sub(ctx, vintedurl):
    x = await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Discord-test")
    with open("config.json", 'w+') as configedit:
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)] = {}
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["url"] = str(vintedurl)
        configs["suburl"][str(x.url)]["salon"] = str(ctx.channel.name)

        json.dump(configs,configedit,indent=4)
    await ctx.send("Webhook ajouté avec le lien !")
```

Docs for custom checks: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple `if else` to check the `ctx.author.id` :)

```
@bot.command()
async def onlytwopplcanuseme(ctx):
    user_ids = [1234567890123456, 1234567890123456] # Replace the two user IDs here
    if ctx.author.id in user_ids:
        await ctx.reply("Approved!")
    else:
        await ctx.reply("Not approved!")
```